# How to update a column which is also a primary key?

Tags: oracle, database-design, primary-key

There is a name field in the UI which is also the primary key column in the underlying table. There is a requirement to make that field editable in the UI. There should be an ID which should serve as the primary key, but there isn't and now it is not feasible to introduce any ID column.

Is there any alternate design idea which can be used in such a scenario ?

The UI is in Swing and DB is Oracle.

Comment: updating primary key doesn't make any sense

Comment: Yes it doesn't. But is there any alternate design pattern by which we can achieve the similar functionality ? As I said, changing the data model to introduce an ID is also not feasible as per the product.

Comment: You _can_ update a PK column. What exactly is your problem? What is the error you get when you do so?

Comment: I'm not getting any error as such, but the cost to update a PK column would be very high as I have to update all the foreign keys that reference this key. The foreign keys are indexed so I believe I need to update the indexes as well.

Comment: how many Foreign key referenced to the PK ?and what do you updateing the indexes ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't know, who thinks `Name` field can be `Primary Key`. That's the wrong database design ever.

Yes, you better change it to some `ID` column as `Primary Key` and that shouldn't be updated in future. Since, you can't have multiple `Primary Key`. So, you need to perform some circus here.

- You need to `drop` existing `Primary Key` first. Since, you can't have multiple `Primary Key` in single table.
- Create your `ID` column and allow `NULL`
- Then, update this column with sequence.
- Once your `ID` column gets populated, you need to create `Primary Key` on this column.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But there are few issues in doing so. This is a legacy product and there was some specific reasons why name was used as a primary key. Since the approach which you suggested, should be the ideal approach, but we cannot go through with it as it would involve huge data model changes.
Could there be any alternate solution to this ?

Comment: @NinadSinghNegi I can't think of any other option as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one primary key, but you can have any number of unique indexes on a table. So let the existing primary key be the immutable primary key and have the application use this key internally for everything. Add another column to the table and create a unique index on it. Let the users modify this other field.

Another alternative would be to declare all child tables with foreign keys ON UPDATE CASCADE. That way, any update to the primary key will cascade to the child tables. Once implemented in production, quit the company and run fast in the other direction and write an article about how you were the first person ever to use ON UPDATE CASCADE in a production setting.